# Duvida sobre " inserção" de váriaveis no comando de entrada no C#?

Tags: c#

Bem, minha duvida é o seguinte, no C# eu consigo usar minhas "constantes" seja ela de qualquer tipo no meu comando de saída, tudo normal.

Porém, se eu uso uma "variável" do tipo `int` ou  `double` e coloco eles no comando de entrada da uma erro de Sintaxe :

> "  Convert type ' string ' to ' int ' "  ou " Convert type ' string '
>   to ' int ' " .

Na mensagem de erro fala para eu converter, eu tenho que sempre converter, por que quando eu uso string não aparece para converter também?

Enfim , posso está falando besteira  mas eu sou bem iniciante na programação e gostaria de esclarecer essa duvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT, não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] e entender como o site funciona. O ideal é que você não use imagens e sim coloque o seu código como texto, o editor possui ferramentas para isso, [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

O método `ReadLine()` contido dentro do `Console` sempre retorna uma string([Veja a documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)), por isso, caso sua variável não seja do tipo `string` será necessária a conversão;

Já o método `WriteLine()`, também contido na classe `Console` recebe parâmetros de diversos tipos diferentes, [vide documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/70x4wcx1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Veja um exemplo:

```
Console.Write("Digite a nota: ");
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int nota))
    Console.WriteLine("Falha ao converter valor para inteiro");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Nota digitada: {nota}");
```

Com o `Console.Write()` está sendo solicitado uma entrada, abaixo tento fazer uma conversão do valor digitado para o tipo `int` com o `int.TryParse`, caso a entrada seja convertida com sucesso é escrito na tela a nota digitada, caso haja falha, isso é informado ao usuário.

Você também pode checar tudo isso na [documentação da classe Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

O comentário do Barbetta é o melhor, contudo deixando de forma mais simplificada.

o código está informando que não compreende o que foi digitado acima, isso porque, na linha

```
Console.Write ("Digite sua nota: ");
```

está recebendo um String (palavra), contudo a variável que ira receber o que foi digitado está esperando receber um Int (número).

Para corrigir isso basta converter o anunciado em número, da seguinte forma:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Assim ele vai receber o que foi digitado acima e depois converter o que recebeu em número.